# Oracle OSB Business Service with OWSM Policy

Tags: oracle, web-services, weblogic, policy, osb

I am creating a Business Service in OSB and I want to select Policies -> OWSM Policies option. However on the screen to this service the option is greyed out. I can still select WLS9 Policies From WSDL or From Pre-defined Policy or WS-Policy Resource.

So I need to find out why OWSM is disabled.

Documentation suggests that this is because WSM Policy manager is not installed but I believe this is not the cause because:

1. In Enterprise Manager I see a metadata repository named msd-owsm
2. If I go to http://soabpm-vm.site:7001/wsm-pm/ and validate I see Policy Manager Status: Operational

I am using the 11.1.1.7 virtual box image (obtained from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/soasuite/learnmore/vmsoa-172279.html) and I am running the Admin server only.
Can anyone suggest other places I can look.

Thanks

Robert

Comment: In the admin console under Deployments, is OWSM Policy Support in OSB Initializer Aplication active and targeted to all of the correct servers?

Comment: In console I have clicked deployments and edited the table to show all results. I can not see any OSB Initializer Application nor anything with OWSM inside it.

Answer (score 0):

After logging into the WLS Admin Console select Deployments in the Domain Structure box on the left. (dev_soasuite --> Deployments)

Look for owsmInitializer

If you don't see it then you will need to install the OWSM EAR file.

To do this, click Install while still on the Deployments page and provide the path to the EAR file.

The general path is /"Middleware Home"/"OSB Home"/lib/common. For the Oracle Pre-installed VM the path should be /oracle/fmwhome/Oracle_OSB1/lib/common.

Click Next and choose the owsmInitializer.ear file. Continue till it is installed successfully.

Once installed go back to the Deployments page and ensure that owsmInitializer is deployed and active.

Restart the server and you should be able to select OWSM policies within OSB.